# Highlight of matching code elements - Visual Studio - C#

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

Is there any help to find out, which option to use (Tools- Optoions- Environment- Fonts and Colors) for changing the background highlight of matching code elements like if/else in the example.
The question is about visual studio and not about visual studio code.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you want is under Tools > Options > Environment > Font and Colors > **Selection Match Editor Highlight**

Then you need to [change Item background.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1tpH.png)